# Post image to facebook album without wallpost about it?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, image-uploading

I'm thinking about a two step OpenGraph image upload workaround (post to album, get photo link, call OpenGraph with the image url), but I need to hide the album post from the user's wall.

If my suspections are right, I can't upload image along an OpenGraph object (thatswhy I want to work around).

**So possible to hide album upload from the user's wall?**

Or the original problem, **possible to upload image file along OpenGraph object?**

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: no_story seems what I'm looking for.